# My ClickOnce Application Installation doesn't install on some computers

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm new to writing windows apps, and I work with MS Visual Studio 2010. I wrote a small app and can install it on my own box, and a few other Windows 7 64 bit boxes at work, but my boss's box won't install it. He probably has half a million virtual servers running, but we tried installing on his local instance (Win7 x64) and a virtual Win XP 32 bit instance. The installation appears to install, but when I run the app, it gives me a dialog box referencing a temporary file in the appData folder, with certain verification information, then just doesn't do anything else. Does this sound familiar to anyone?

(The app is a win form with Tabcontrol, it creates MS word and excel docs, and uses the OLEDB library for opening DBF files. That's it, nothing more.)